# issue with merging data from 6 tables into 1gridview

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I have merged 6tables with 7th table and when i bind with Gridview i am getting data like below. but i want data to Come side by side.

Below GridView i am getting :

```
srno   name   FA1 FA2 SA1 FA1 FA2 SA1
1       ABC   1    2   3  
2       XYZ   1    2   3
3       ABC               1    2   3
4       XYZ               1    2   3
```

I Want my gridview to look like below :

```
srno   name   FA1 FA2 SA1 FA1 FA2 SA1
1       ABC   1    2   3  1    2   3
2       XYZ   1    2   3  1    2   3
```

Here is my Sql Query Which runs for 6different subjects store data into datatables and then merge into another datatable.

```
select f1.FA1 as FA1san,f1.FA1Total as FA1Totalsan,f2.FA2 as FA2san,f2.FA2Total as FA2Totalsan,f3.FA3 as FA3san,f3.FA3Total as FA3Totalsan,f4.FA4 as FA4san,f4.FA4Total as FA4Totalsan,sa1.SA1 as SA1san,sa1.SA1Total as SA1Totalsan,sa2.SA2 as SA2san,sa2.SA2Total as SA2Totalsan from ViewFa1 f1 inner join StudentDetails s on f1.StudentId=s.Id inner join ClassTable c on f1.StudentId=c.StudentId left join ViewFa2 f2 on f1.StudentId=f2.StudentId and f1.SubjectId=f2.SubjectId left join ViewFa3 f3 on f1.StudentId=f3.StudentId and f1.SubjectId=f3.SubjectId left join ViewFa4 f4 on f1.StudentId=f4.StudentId and f1.SubjectId=f4.SubjectId left join ViewSa1 sa1 on f1.StudentId=sa1.StudentId and f1.SubjectId=sa1.SubjectId left join ViewSa2 sa2 on f1.StudentId=sa2.StudentId and f1.SubjectId=sa2.SubjectId order by s.FirstName
```

Comment: As posted currently we can't offer much help because you haven't offered much in the way of details. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Edited Sir @SeanLange

Comment: You really want to have two columns names the same thing in your datagrid? That seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Now you have posted a query but it doesn't match what you stated you are getting as a result. You seem to have some pretty serious normalization issues since you views with numbers and columns with numbers. This sounds a lot like you have repeating groups which violates 1NF. Regardless the answer I posted is an example of how to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is still extremely vague. You are looking for a code answer but have provided barely any information about your tables. I am guessing you want something like this. I question your decision about having two columns named the same thing in your gridview but that is your choice.

```
select srno = MIN(t1.srno)
    , t1.name
    , FA1 = max(t1.FA1) 
    , FA2 = max(t1.FA2) 
    , SA1 = max(t1.SA1) 
    , FA1 = max(t2.FA1) 
    , FA2 = max(t2.FA2) 
    , SA1 = max(t2.SA1) 
from Table1 t1
join Table2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
group by t1.name
```

Comment: Actually Header of first three Columns would be different and like wise next three. and header will be generated  via code behind.

Comment: OK. I had to use what you stated you want them to be in your question. Regardless that query should get you the basic concept of what you need.